# Как в radare2 сохранить блок данных по смещению и определенным размером?

Tags: reverse-engineering, radare2

Программа статическая и нужно определенный кусок кода сохранить в файл. я даже не знаю что пробовать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `s 0x1000` - перейти на нужное смещение в файле
- `wtf filename.bin 0x2000` - записать 0x2000 байт из открытого файла в файл filename.bin